# How does the serialisation using child class of ObjectOutputStream does not give error when reading the objects using ObjectInputStream?

Tags: java, serialization, deserialization, file-handling, objectoutputstream

When serialising multiple time using ObjectOutputStream object it was setting the new header at the end of file each time. While reading the Object it was throwing the StreamCorruptedException . This problem was solved by making the child class of ObjectOutputStream and using child class Object to serialise data .

```
public class SerializeDataInAndOut {
    private File f=new File("studentFile.txt");
    public SerializeDataInAndOut()  {
        try {
            // Creating new file using File object above
            f.createNewFile();
        }

        // Catch block to handle the exception
        catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Exception Occured!");
        }
    }

    public void addData(Student student)
    {
        FileOutputStream fileOutputStream=null;
        try{
            fileOutputStream=new FileOutputStream("studentFile.txt", true);
        }
        catch(FileNotFoundException ex){
            System.out.println("File Not Found!");
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            System.out.println("Exception Occured!");
        }

        if(f.length()==0) {
            try (ObjectOutputStream outputStream = new ObjectOutputStream(fileOutputStream)) {

                outputStream.writeObject(student);
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                System.out.println("Error occured while writing data in file");
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        else{
            try (MyObjectOutputStream myOutputStream = new MyObjectOutputStream(fileOutputStream)) {
                myOutputStream.writeObject(student);
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                System.out.println("Error occured while writing data in file");
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        try{
            fileOutputStream.close();
        }
        catch (IOException ex)
        {
            System.out.println("Input Output Exception Occured!");
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

    public List<Student> getData() {

        if(f.length()==0)
        {
            System.out.println("No Record Found!!!");
            return null;
        }
        List<Student> allStudents=new ArrayList<>();
        FileInputStream fileInputStream=null;
        try{
            fileInputStream= new FileInputStream("studentFile.txt");
        }
        catch(FileNotFoundException ex){
            System.out.println("File Not Found!");
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
        catch (Exception ex) {
            System.out.println("Exception Occured!");
        }

        try(ObjectInputStream inputStream=new ObjectInputStream(fileInputStream)){

            System.out.println("Getting Object ");
            while(true) {
                try{
                    Student student=(Student) inputStream.readObject();
                    allStudents.add(student);
                }
                catch(EOFException ex){
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        catch(IOException ex) {
            System.out.println("Exception Occured!");
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
        catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            System.out.println("Error Class not Found!");
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
        return allStudents;
    }
}
```

Here is the child class of ObjectOutputStream

```
class MyObjectOutputStream extends ObjectOutputStream{

    public MyObjectOutputStream(OutputStream out) throws IOException {
        super(out);
    }

    public MyObjectOutputStream() throws IOException {
        super();
    }

    public void writeStreamHeader() throws IOException
    {
        return;
    }

}
```

My question here is that how serialising with child class object is not giving me an exception , here also we are creating the new Object of the child class of ObjectOutputStream , will not set the header each time?

Comment: Because (1) `MyObjectOutputStream.writeStreamHeader()` does nothing, and (2) you are only using `MyObjectOutputStream` to append to the file, which already has the header written by `ObjectOutputStream` the first time, when the file was empty.